# Defining chained string transform functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chaining, method-chaining

[Chaining Methods, also known as Cascading](http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/), refers to repeatedly calling one method after another on an object, in one continuous line of code.

Writing code like this:

```
str.replace("k", "R").toUpperCase().substr(0,4);
```

is not just pleasurable and convenient but also succinct and intelligible. It allows us to read code like a sentence, flowing gracefully across the page. It also frees us from the monotonous, blocky structures we usually construct.

[This blog](http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/) talks about how to do it generally, however considering extending the String prototype will be good enough for my case, I don't know whether it is an overkill or not.

Basically I don't know enough Javascript to make the judgement call of,

- whether go with the above general way,
- or just extend the String prototype, knowing that it is [generally a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/)
- or maybe using [function wrapper](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions) (or maybe it is totally irrelevant)
- I also know the following is another option, but it's kind of rigid, I.e., translated into my case, it means the string transform can only be
  `replace("k", "R")` then followed by `toUpperCase()` then followed by substr(0,4).

```js
// https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1
console.log('Begin');

const withConstructor = constructor => o => {
  const proto = Object.assign({},
Object.getPrototypeOf(o),
{ constructor }
  );
  return Object.assign(Object.create(proto), o);
};

const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
// or `import pipe from 'lodash/fp/flow';`
// Set up some functional mixins
const withFlying = o => {
  let isFlying = false;
  return {
...o,
fly () {
  isFlying = true;
  return this;
},
land () {
  isFlying = false;
  return this;
},
isFlying: () => isFlying
  }
};
const withBattery = ({ capacity }) => o => {
  let percentCharged = 100;
  return {
...o,
draw (percent) {
  const remaining = percentCharged - percent;
  percentCharged = remaining > 0 ? remaining : 0;
  return this;
},
getCharge: () => percentCharged,
get capacity () {
  return capacity
}
  };
};
const createDrone = ({ capacity = '3000mAh' }) => pipe(
  withFlying,
  withBattery({ capacity }),
  withConstructor(createDrone)
)({});
const myDrone = createDrone({ capacity: '5500mAh' });
console.log(`
  can fly:  ${ myDrone.fly().isFlying() === true }
  can land: ${ myDrone.land().isFlying() === false }
  battery capacity: ${ myDrone.capacity }
  battery status: ${ myDrone.draw(50).getCharge() }%
  battery drained: ${ myDrone.draw(75).getCharge() }%
`);
console.log(`
  constructor linked: ${ myDrone.constructor === createDrone }
`);

console.log('End');
```

To make it simple, I need to define my own functions like

```
str.transform1("k", "R").transform2().transform3(0,4);
```

that do just as

```
str.replace("k", "R").toUpperCase().substr(0,4);
```

In reality each function will be a set of complicated `replace()` function call, but let's make it simple for this question.

What best should I do?

Comment: I think the only way this can work is to extend string prototype - which you already know is generally bad practice :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks for the conformation. That's what I'm planning to do so far. Just to see if there is any betters ways before making my dive, :)